# how To get specific part of a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string

```
string a = "(something is there),xyz,(something there)";
```

and, I use this

```
string s = "(something is there),xyz,(something there)";
int start = s.IndexOf("(") + 1;
int end = s.IndexOf(")", start);
string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

but I want to use the second part `(something there)`
how can I do it?

Comment: Regex would help. Or your can use `LastIndexOf`, or you can use the `IndexOf` overload that lets you specify the starting index to search from (use the index of the last search + 1). Or you could split on `,` and take the last element.

Comment: What's wrong with a regex? `@"\([^()]*\)(?=[^()]*$)"`

Comment: Do you always want the 2nd `(` as the start or do you always want the contents of both?

Comment: String split should help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What's with the (seemingly) serial downvoting on perfectly good answers?

Comment: I don't know @MattBurland I think there is a madman on the lose

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate of an already-answered question here at SO?  Then again, six people with close-vote capabilities answered, so it must not be

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what exactly you're doing around this, however this does it in this specific case:

```
var last = s.Split(',').Last(); // "(something there)"
```

Or more verbosely for explanation:

```
var s = "(something is there),xyz,(something there)";

var split = s.Split(','); // [ "(something is there)", "xyz", "(something there)" ]

var last = split.Last(); // "(something there)"
```

And if you don't want the brackets<sup>(en-GB)</sup>

```
var content = last.Trim('(', ')'); // "something there"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a.Split("(),".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will return an array with 3 strings: `something is there`, `xyz`, and `something there`

Comment: but OP does **not** want `xyz`.

Comment: @MickyDuncan - probably not -- the requirements are very vague.  I figured this was the best way to do the `spit()` and no one else had shown it.

Comment: I like this because I am actually trying to get the one in the middle. Now to print out xyz, how would I print out xyz at array [1]? I guess put it into string[] and call it out.

Answer (score 3):

If "last" is the same as "second" in this case you can use `String.LastIndexOf`:

```
string lastPart = null;
int lastStartIndex = a.LastIndexOf('(');
if (lastStartIndex >= 0)
{
    int lastEndIndex = a.LastIndexOf(')');
    if (lastEndIndex >= 0)
        lastPart = a.Substring(++lastStartIndex, lastEndIndex - lastStartIndex);
}
```

---

Here is a solution which extracts all tokens from the string into a `List<string>`:

```
int startIndex = -1, endIndex = -1;
var tokens = new List<string>();
while (true)
{
    startIndex = a.IndexOf('(', ++endIndex);
    if (startIndex == -1) break;
    endIndex = a.IndexOf(')', ++startIndex);
    if (endIndex == -1) break;
    tokens.Add(a.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
}
```

So now you could use the indexer or `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`:

```
string first = tokens[0];
string second = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

If the list is too small you get `null` as result.  If you just want the last use `tokens.Last()`.

Comment: a bit verbose compared to the other answers perhaps?

Comment: @MickyDuncan: i have provided an even more verbose approach which enables to extract all parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
  string s = "(something is there),xyz,(something there)";
   var start = s.Split(',')[2];
```

Also You can use:

```
        string s = "(something is there),xyz,(something there)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\([^()]*\)(?=[^()]*$)");
        Match match = regex.Match("(something is there),xyz,(something there)");
        var result = match.Value;
```

Comment: Completely mystified why somebody would downvote this. Seems like the simplest solution to the *specific* problem as the OP presented.

Comment: Why string a= required ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following if you just want the text:

```
var s = "(something is there),xyz,(something there)";
var splits = s.Split('(');
var text = splits[2].Trim(')');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text between second '(' and ')' then use the second parameter of `IndexOf` which sets the starting index for searching

```
start = s.IndexOf("(", end) + 1;
end = s.IndexOf(")", start);
string secondResult = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

If you want to get the string after the last `)` use this code:

```
string otherPart = s.Substring(end+1);
```